# php redirecting page and not sending email

Tags: php

When a I hit submit on my form, the form redirect's me to "process.php" and the email doesn't send, but when I hit refresh it sends the email with garbage in it. How can I get PHP not to redirect me to a different page and send the email based on what's in the form.

Here's my code

PHP

```
$toemail = 'email@gmail.com';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
if(mail($toemail, 'Subject', $message, 'From: ' . $email)) {
    echo 'Your email was sent successfully.';
} else {
    echo 'There was a problem sending your email.';
}
```

HTML

```
<h2>Leave a message</h2>
  <div class="sepContainer"></div>
  <form action="process.php" method="post" id="contact_form">
    <div class="name">
      <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
      <p> Please enter your full name</p>
      <input id=name name=name type=text placeholder="e.g. Mr. John Smith" required />
    </div>
    <div class="email">
      <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
      <p> Please enter your email address</p>
      <input id=email name=email type=email placeholder="example@domain.com" required />
    </div>
    <div class="message">
      <label for="message">Your Message:</label>
      <p> Please enter your question</p>
      <textarea id=message name=message rows=6 cols=10 required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="loader">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </form>
```

It's hosted on a Unix server. Try not to be to harsh I've only been learning PHP for 2 days now.

Comment: Note: best to wrap your form attributes with `"` -> `id="email"` just to enclose it all properly.

Comment: As Darren mentioned, definitely use quotes around your `id` and `name` attributes in HTML.  Also, try echoing your POST variables to make sure they contain what you think they do before you try sending the mail.  You can do that  like this:  `echo 'Name: ', $_POST['name'], 'Email: ', $_POST['email'], ' Message: ', $_POST['message'];`

Comment: I did that, and it is indeed echoing everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
$name = $_POST ['name'];
$request = $_POST['request'];

$to = "(email goes here)";
$subject = "Website Quote";
$body = "This is an automated message. Please do not reply to this emai. \n\n $request";

mail ($to,$subject,$body);

echo "Message Sent. <a href='index.html'>Click here to return to the site.</a>"
 ?>
```

Here is REALLY basic PHP code to send an email, which is what it seems like you're attempting to do.

HTML -

```
 <form action="send.php" method="POST">
      Name: <br> <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      Request <br> <textarea name="request"></textarea><br><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
```

Hopefully this clears something up, if I approached this incorrectly please explain it differently, thanks, have a great day!